# Sync MySQL and MSSQL databases through windows service

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, windows-services

I must sync 2 tables of two databases one of which is a MSSQL and the other one MySQL. I have to do this through a Windows Service. I currently have created a Windows Service, and what I currently have added to the service is : getting the data from the MySQL database and inserting it into a Data Adapter from which I plan to move the data to the MSSQL database using an insertion through transaction.Can you tell me what is the best approach to this problem and if what I'm doing right now is on the right track, first time I'm doing such a thing.

Comment: Have you tried using SSIS for synchronization of such heterogeneous database like MySQL to MSSQL? That might get your work done.

Answer (score 1):

Well, probably there is a couple ways to solve this.  You didn't mention about count and size of your tables, desired synchronization frequency so my answer might be not 100% relevant. Anyway my proposal is:

1. Each table should have additional column - SyncDate (TIMESTAMP) which by default is null.
2. Sync logic which is implemented in Windows Service periodically checks each table if there is some data to sync by executing query like this (use pure IDataReader for performance reasons):

   SELECT * from TEST_TABLE where SyncDate is null
3. If above statement returns data then:

   - collect package of rows to insert (for example 500 rows)
   - begin transaction on target database and execute insert statement for collected package (set value for column SyncDate to DateTime.Now)
   - when insert is complete execute statement like this in source db:

   UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET SyncDate = @DateTime.Now where ID_PRIMARY_KEY IN (IDENTIFIRES FROM PACKAGE)

   - commit transaction
   - collect another packages and repeat algorithm until DataReader provides data
4. Above algorithm should be applied on both databases
5. Probably your database has foreign keys so you have to remember that dependant tables should be synchronized in valid order
6. Wherever it possible you can benefit from multi threading

Comment: one point though. The tables in two database should be compared in the code otherwise will be inserting duplicates records which we don't want. May be you can shed some light on that part?

Comment: Redundancy sometimes is not that bad but of course it depends on business model and usually it is better to avoid it. To do so I don't see any other way than comparing records however doing this by executing query with where clause having all columns in table does not sound perfect. A little bit smarter approach would be additional column RecordHash containing unique identifier generated during insert based on values from all other columns except SyncDate and Primary Key Id. Having such structure before inserting data do target table you have to execute query which checks which data are new.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of job, SQL Server Integration Services is the way to go.

SSIS is made to Extract, transform, and load data. (ETL process)

You design a worklow with each transformation step of your data, from MySQL to MSSQL.

You then create a job and configure its schedule, and it will be executed by SQL Server.

No need to develop something from scratch and hard to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

If you are already at a point where you are ready to move the MySQL data to SQL. I would suggest you put them on a separate table and issue a Merge command to merge the data. Make sure that you flag back the data that has been updated so you can now get them back and push to MySQL:

```
MERGE TableFromMySQL AS TARGET USING TableFromSQL AS SOURCE
    ON (TARGET.PrimaryKey = SOURCE.PrimaryKey)
         WHEN Matched AND (TARGET.Field1 <> SOURCE.Field1
            OR TARGET.Field2 <> SOURCE.Field2
            OR .. put more field comparison here that you want to sync
         THEN
            UPDATE
            SET TARGET.Field1 = SOURCE.Field1,
                TARGET.Field2 = SOURCE.Field2,
                //flag the target field as updated
                TARGET.IsUpdated = 1,
                TARGET.LastUpdatedOn = GETDATE()
            WHEN Not Matched 
            THEN
    INSERT(PrimaryKey, Field1, Field2, IsUpdated, LastUpdatedOn)
    VALUES(SOURCE.PrimaryKey, SOURCE.Field1, SOURCE.Field2, 1, GETDATE());
```

At this point, you can now query the MySQL table with IsUpdated = 1 and push all values to MYSQL database. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the mySql database as a linked server (sp_addlinkedserver) then I think you could do the following in a stored proc on your MS SQL database:

```
 insert table1(col1) 
 select col1 
 from openquery('MySqlLinkedDb','select col1 from mySqlDb.dbo.table2')
```

Comment: You don't add the linked server via C#, you do it via Sql server Management Studio. check this out: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx. The linked server name is equivalent to MySqlLinkedDb above. Once you have added it you can check the list of servers linked via select * from sys.servers.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution using the Microsoft Sync Framework. Maybe you do have some experience with it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this through a Windows Service, I am curious how you are receiving the data from MySQL?  What is initiating the call to the service and what form is the data passed in?  Are you getting changes or are you getting a couple refresh of the data?

If you receive a DataTable or some other kind of IEnumerable and its a complete refresh, for example, you could use SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer().  That would be the fastest and most efficient.

Tom